# Finding the src of an image via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I found the answer to my question via a simple Google search, although, there is a slight problem that I ran into.

So far, I have an image on my HTML page with the ID of newAvatar. I am attempting to find this image via its ID, and save it's source into a variable, then eventually into an XML document to be used later on.

When I save this source into a variable, or alert it for checking purposes, it is displaying the full source, which is unusual. For example, I am running my site on a WAMP server, so the variable is saving as:

```
http://localhost/uploads/newUploadedImage.jpg
```

When in reality, the source should be plain and simple, uploads/newUploadedImage.jpg

The image tag is

```
<img src="uploads/newUploadedImage.jpg" width="60px" height="60px;" id="newAvatar"/>
```

The way i am checking the source is

```
alert(document.getElementById('newAvatar').src);
```

Any idea how to get rid of the first lot of junk?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the javascript and image tag in your question?

Comment: Possibly `this.getAttribute('src');` but without context (your html and JavaScript) it's very hard to say, or guess.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Added the info you asked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using @DavidThomas comment before, I managed to get it working. This is what i changed my alert to:

```
alert(document.getElementById('newAvatar').getAttribute('src'));
```

Comment: Check this works in other browsers - I think older versions of IE might have a problem. Might need to use a framework like jQuery to ensure better cross-browser compatibility: `$('#newAvatar').attr('src')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var hostname = document.location.hostname;
var url = 'http://' + hostname + '/';

var src = document.getElementById('newAvatar').getAttribute('src'); //'uploads/newUploadedImage.jpg'
var image = src.split('/')[1];

console.log(url);
console.log(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<img src="uploads/newUploadedImage.jpg" width="60px" height="60px;"
  id="newAvatar"/>
```

and

```
$(function()
{
    alert($('#newAvatar').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: @epascarello Added the ready event handler around the alert call.